# Why is QEditLine automatically selected in PyQt5 when launching app?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qlineedit

I know it's a bit useless to ask this but I'm curious and I just want to understand. I have 2 windows (login and signup). Each window has 2 or 3 QLineEdit and some labels + buttons. I wondered why in one window, the QLineEdit is automatically selected when I open it (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3jkB.png)) and in the other, the QLineEdit isn't automatically selected when I open it (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uByea.png)). I searched into my code and did not see any differences that would explain this.

I know it's not that important but I want to understand why this happens.

Here is a little window that reproduces the *problem*.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui(object):

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setFixedSize(130, 60)

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
    
        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 113, 20))
        self.line.setObjectName("line")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the second UI (simplified):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_Signup(object):

    def setupUi(self, Signup_Dialog):
        Signup_Dialog.setObjectName("Signup_Dialog")
        Signup_Dialog.setFixedSize(251, 179)
    
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(8)

        self.create_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Signup_Dialog)
        self.create_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 140, 91, 21))
        self.create_button.setFont(font)
        self.create_button.setObjectName("create_button")

        self.username = QtWidgets.QLabel(Signup_Dialog)
        self.username.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 101, 20))
        self.username.setFont(font)
        self.username.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.username.setObjectName("username")

        self.username_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Signup_Dialog)
        self.username_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 121, 20))
        self.username_line.setObjectName("username_line")

        self.retranslateUi(Signup_Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Signup_Dialog)

    

    def retranslateUi(self, Signup_Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Signup_Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Signup_Dialog", "Sign Up"))
        self.username.setText(_translate("Signup_Dialog", "Create Username"))
        self.create_button.setText(_translate("Signup_Dialog", "Create"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Signup_Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Signup()
    ui.setupUi(Signup_Dialog)
    Signup_Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Does anyone know why the line is automaticaly selected?

Comment: The exact reason may depend on several different factors, and you haven't really provided enough information regarding those. See, for example, [QWidget.activateWindow()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#activateWindow), [QWidget.setTabOrder()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setTabOrder) and [Keyboard Focus in Widgets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/focus.html).

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution. I put the focus on a label with setFocus() and it worked, the QLineEdit is no longer automatically selected!

Comment: @Reywaz that is just a temporary workaround that might not work in all situations (what if you do *not* have a label?) and does not solve the issue nor answer the question; besides, the problem could still raise if the user presses the tab key, as the next focused widget might be different for those dialogs, which would make the UI behavior confusing and annoying to the user - and, yes, it *is* important. If you want an *actual* answer, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I modified the question, let me know if you find a better answer! Thank you

Comment: @Reywaz please include the second UI too, so that we can better explain the differences.

Comment: @Reywaz I got to reopen your question, so that it can now accept answers again. Can you please clarify if your question is just about *why* that happens, or if you specifically want that a window with just a *single* line edit does *not* set the focus on it? Normally, this requirement is for windows that have multiple widgets and *another* widgets automatically gets the focus (for instance, a button, similarly to your second example).

Comment: @musicamante oh so the focus is on the button and that's why the line isn't automatically selected? And I would like to know how how not to set the focus on anything, for example in the window with only a single lineedit. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a top level window is activated (including when shown the first time), it automatically sets the focus to the *first* widget that accepts input focus.

Note that "first" can be misleading, as it depends on two factors:

- the order in which widgets are added to a parent (including grand-children, grand-parents, etc);
- the order overridden by the [`setTabOrder()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setTabOrder) static function

Note that the first aspect is also the *creation* order *only* for widgets created with a parent, if layout managers are used and widgets have no parent set in their constructor, the order completely depends on the layout insertion order; this refers to the *moment* in which the widget was added, and does not consider the position in the layout (i.e. using `insertWidget()`). Also, explcitly calling `setParent()` on the widget will *not* change anything in the focus order.

The above explains why in your second example you get the focus on the button instead of the line edit: the button was created *first*, and with the parent argument in its constructor.

To prevent *any* focus stealing from any widget that accepts focus, the solution is pretty simple: call `setFocus()` on the top level window. In the first example above, it would be:

```
Dialog.setFocus()
```

Be aware that disabling the default auto focus on a new window is not suggested and may result *very* annoying to the user (I would), and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> after that will resume the normal tab order anyway (as above, following the creation order or based on `setTabOrder()`)

<sup>Note that I'm assuming that the code above was "simplified" for the sake of the examples: 1. you're not supposed to edit pyuic files, but instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) (in this case, it would probably be a QDialog subclass and you'd be calling `self.setFocus()` in the `__init__` right after `setupUi()`); 2. you shall always use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html);</sup>